# can't decode JSON request body: malformed JSON using Laravel ixdra/curl package

Tags: laravel

`Curl statemet is`

```bash
if [ -z "$STABILITY_API_KEY" ]; then
    echo "STABILITY_API_KEY environment variable is not set"
    exit 1
fi

OUTPUT_FILE=./out/v1_txt2img.png
BASE_URL=${API_HOST:-https://api.stability.ai}
URL="$BASE_URL/v1/generation/stable-diffusion-v1-5/text-to-image"

curl -f -sS -X POST "$URL" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: image/png' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $STABILITY_API_KEY" \
  --data-raw '{
    "text_prompts": [
      {
        "text": "A lighthouse on a cliff"
      }
    ],
    "cfg_scale": 7,
    "clip_guidance_preset": "FAST_BLUE",
    "height": 512,
    "width": 512,
    "samples": 1,
    "steps": 30
  }' \
  -o "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

> 'My ixdra/curl code in laravel is'

```php
$response = Curl::to('https://api.stability.ai/v1/generation/stable-diffusion-v1-5/text-to-image')
    ->withContentType('application/json')
    ->withHeader('Authorization: Bearer sk-4TbivezpfB32bHGzaIbPd5S0NIzHQsN141kZ4FW0H31TrnLr')
    ->withData(array(
        "text_prompts"  => array(  "text" => $prompts ) ,
        "cfg_scale" => 7,
        "clip_guidance_preset" => 'FAST_BLUE',
        "height" => 512,
        "width" => 512,
        "samples" => 1,
        "steps" => 30
    ))
    ->post();
```

please help  me to solve the error ?

error :: "{"id":"dba28c896eb85a892b376b3f87bff0e7","message":"can't decode JSON request body: malformed JSON","name":"bad_request"}"

> 'What is coorect code in json request body ? '

Comment: Are you sure `$prompts` is a string?

Comment: $prompts is a string

Comment: I think you need to chain `->asJson()` as well

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Actuall I have use the ixdra/curl package Larvel, and when I try make the json request

Comment: "text_prompts": [
      {
        "text": "A lighthouse on a cliff"
      }
    ],

Comment: how to write the ixdra/curl package code

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure `$prompts` is a string.
- You seem to be missing the `->asJson()` call.

Try either

```php
$prompts = 'A lighthouse on a cliff';
$url = 'https://api.stability.ai/v1/generation/stable-diffusion-v1-5/text-to-image';
$key = 'sk-4TbivezpfB32bHGzaIbPd5S0NIzHQsN141kZ4FW0H31TrnLr';
$data = [
    'text_prompts' => [
        'text' => $prompts
    ],
    'cfg_scale' => 7,
    'clip_guidance_preset' => 'FAST_BLUE',
    'height' => 512,
    'width' => 512,
    'samples' => 1,
    'steps' => 30
];

$response = Curl::to($url)
    ->withContentType('application/json')
    ->withHeader('Authorization: Bearer ' . $key)
    ->withData($data)
    ->asJson()
    ->post();
```

or

```php
$prompts = 'A lighthouse on a cliff';
$url = 'https://api.stability.ai/v1/generation/stable-diffusion-v1-5/text-to-image';
$key = 'sk-4TbivezpfB32bHGzaIbPd5S0NIzHQsN141kZ4FW0H31TrnLr';
$data = [
    'text_prompts' => [
        'text' => $prompts
    ],
    'cfg_scale' => 7,
    'clip_guidance_preset' => 'FAST_BLUE',
    'height' => 512,
    'width' => 512,
    'samples' => 1,
    'steps' => 30
];

$response = Curl::to($url)
    ->withContentType('application/json')
    ->withHeader('Authorization: Bearer ' . $key)
    ->withData(json_encode($data))
    ->post();
```

Comment: I have use the 1st code block - then the error shows -

Comment: {#1433 ▼
  +"id": "5a2d985aed28fa0c32cc194eafa297ce"
  +"message": "content-type: must be application/json"
  +"name": "bad_request"
}

Comment: What if you remove the `->withContentType('application/json')` line?

Comment: error :{#1433 ▼
  +"id": "98162f018ea3a67776117bec31943111"
  +"message": "can't decode JSON request body: malformed JSON"
  +"name": "bad_request"
}